# ActionScript join/split

Tags: php, arrays, flash, actionscript

Hi guys I have to port a few functions from AS to PHP, but I ran into a small problem.

There's an array, lets called it arr1. There is a switch, that pushes argument to this array, but after the switch ends, I'm stuck at `join("").split("");`

```
var arr1 = [];
    switch (myString)
    {
        case "apple":
        {
            arr1.push("apple");
            break;
        } 
    }
}
arr1 = arr1.join("").split("");
```

I know is simple, but i never had experience with arrays in flash before, I just realized `join("")` was used to convert the Array to string, but isn't split reversing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this code is doing is first joining all your array values together into a string, and then splitting them into an array of the separate characters.  The PHP equivalent would look something this ([tested](http://testing.subdmedia.com/so/6777802/)):

```
$arr1 = array("apple");  //arr1 after the switch
$arr1 = str_split(implode('',$arr1));
```

Comment: For some reason its not correct implementation, my function errors out.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. explode() doesn't allow an empty delimiter, you have to use `str_split()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

[`join(delimiter:*)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#join%28%29) will create a string from an array where each of the items from the array are separated by whatever the delimiter is (defaults to NaN, if you're interested).

[`split(delimiter:*, limit:Number = 0x7fffffff)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#split%28%29) beaks a string into an array of limit length based on whatever is the delimiter.

while this may look like it should output the same array consistently:

```
var delim:String = "someString";
arr.join(delim).split(delim)
```

In this case, it will actually result in a different array:

```
var arr:Array = ['asomeStringb','c','d']
var delim:String = "someString";
trace(arr.join(delim).split(delim))//[a,b,c,d]
```

If delimiter is an empty string for split, it will break the string up character by character:

```
var arr:Array = ['ab','c','d']
var delim:String = "";
trace(arr.join(delim).split(delim))//[a,b,c,d]
```

Hope that helps.

PHP equivalent might be:

```
$input = array( /*stuff...*/ );
// join is an alias of implode. I used it here because the AS method is join.
$input = /* explode( <-- won't work */ str_split( "", join($input));
```

Side note: in AS3 always type your variables as strictly as possible -- it really helps in the end. `var arr1` should be `var arr1:Array`.

Comment: Im sorry, but what should be the PHP equivalent to this?

Comment: See my comment to my answer, you can't use `explode` with an empty delimiter.